# Why does the order of column names in GROUP BY clause matter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have observed that the order of the rows displayed (for the query) depends on the **Order of Column** names in **GROUP BY CLAUSE**

**Scenario 1:**

```
SELECT customer_id, staff_id, SUM(amount) 
FROM payment
GROUP BY staff_id, customer_id
```

Results for Scenario 1:

[image]

**Scenario 2:**

```
SELECT customer_id, staff_id, SUM(amount) 
FROM payment
GROUP BY customer_id, staff_id
```

Results for Scenario 2:

[image]

Comment: In postgresql, if you don't specify ORDER BY, the order of rows in UNDEFINED and can be random: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html `If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order.` So, if you not using ORDER BY, you can just ignore the ordering of rows, it doesn't has any special sense

Comment: @MihanEntalpo Rows are not returned in a random order. The ordering is unspecified and can change at any time in the future without notice.

Comment: It's good programming practice to have the same column order in the GROUP BY as in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Without ORDER BY, there is no order. Because of that, any order is fine, is a correct result. And if you do need an order, it’s up to you to tell the database what order you want.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks for the clarification. I didn't mean random as in "randomized intentionally by RDBS" but as in "unknown and unexpected"

Answer (score 3):

The *order* in which rows are returned as a result of a query where you do not specify an `order by` criteria is *completely* arbitrary and at the whim of the database engine.

While you might see ordering of results vary based on numerous factors (i.e. the order in which rows are listed in the *group by* clause per your example), without the `order by` clause the query engine is free to return rows in *any* order it sees fit.

You are seeing a different set of results purely as a result of varying internal query processing steps, but it's *not* "determining" the ordering in any meaningful way.

You may run the same query without an `order by` 1000 times and get identical results, but it's not a guarantee the 1001th execution will, all other factors equal, be the same.

Any result set, even a simple `select * from table` will be presented in any order the engine chooses, unless you explicitely define the order.